# Reading from DB and Writing to File

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio, file-io

Scenario - There is huge data in database. Utility uses datareader to read the records one by one and appends to a txt/xml file. Originally utility used to read one record, write it to file; Then i changed it so that around 10k records are read and put into memory (stringbuilder) and then flushed to file and so on. The time reduction was superb.

So, i guess File I/O was the bottleneck. I want to improve it further. Thinking to use some kind of buffer, and then use one thread to read from DB and put to buffer, and another thread to fetch from buffer and write to File.

Is it possible. Where to start?
Any better alternatives?

Comment: Firstly - how fast can you read the data, and how fast can you write the data? What is your current throughput?

Comment: Around .4 million records - Read single record, write to file (time taken - 6mins), - read 10k records, write to file (time taken - 1min 40s), - read 20k records, write to file (time taken - 1 min 50s)

Comment: Marginally slower to read twice as many records - interesting.  There must be a large setup cost there.

Answer (score 0):

A starting point would be using two buffers, and asynchronously writing the buffer content to the file. Something like:

```
buffera
bufferb
currentbuffer=buffera

fill currentbuffer with data
kickoff job to write currentbuffer to file
wait for previous write job to finish, if relevant.    
currentbuffer=otherbuffer
```

Repeat until complete.

Comment: This should give you an idea of whether you can improve by using multiple threads. Of course the writing process MUST be done in a single thread, so wach will have to wait for the previous one - maybe lock the section. It shoudl be straightforward to achieve this, and see how much difference it makes.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need better performance, you could read the data in chunks of 10k, like you do today, passing in start/end values to the database and write them simultaneously to separate files using multiple threads. On completion, you concatenate/merge/append the files. Writing to a single file can only have so much improvement because the data write has to be sequential.

something like,

```
using (var output = File.Create("output"))
{
    foreach (var file in new[] { "file1", "file2" })
    {
        using (var input = File.OpenRead(file))
        {
            input.CopyTo(output);
        }
    }
}
```

Not sure if it really improves performance by a big margin, but worth a shot.